# Swipe Within and iframe or Something Similar

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, jquery-mobile

Heyo,

Hopefully this is a simple question with a simple answer... Is there any way to create an html doc with an iframe or something similar, which would load a webpage, but allow you to swipe back and forth between pages?  something like

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Blent</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.pagination.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js">      </script>
<script src="jquery.mobile.pagination.js"></script>
<!-- Prevent scaling -->
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
<!-- Eliminate url and button bars if added to home screen -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
</head>
<body>
<iframe id=”the-frame” src=”http://google.com”></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

So I have the iFrame with google in it, and if I swipe, it would load say Amazon.com, and then if I swiped back, it would load Google.  Any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that you would offend the same-origin-policy. Therefore you won't be able to do anything within the iframe with javascript (no matter whether it's jquery, mootools, vanilla or anything other).

there ***could*** however be a chance if you created multiple IFRAMEs in multiple DIVs and swipe the latter...